confusion on notation and action
I was reading one lecture note, what is what is $v(x_{i}^{1})$ here how it is defined. Thank you. I couldn't find in before of the lecture note.
Proposition A
The tangent bundle TM of any given manifold is, in fact, a vector bundle of rank $n$.
[ Warning: There are choices involved!]
Proof:

first, define candidates for charts on the total space
choose countable atlas
$\mathcal{A}=\left\{\left(\varphi_i=\left(x_i^1, \ldots, x_i^n\right), U_i\right) \mid i \in A\right\}$ on $M$
$\pi$ smooth by assumption $\Rightarrow\left\{\pi^{-1}\left(U_i\right) \mid i \in A\right\}$ are open covering of $T M$
define candidates for charts as maps between sets
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \psi_i: \pi^{-1}\left(U_i\right) \rightarrow \varphi_i\left(U_i\right) \times \mathbb{R}^n, \\
& \psi_i: v \mapsto\left(\varphi_i(\pi(v)), v\left(x_i^1\right), \ldots, v\left(x_i^n\right)\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
observe: each $\psi_i$ is a bijection


Is $v$ a derivation? Then think how derivations act on functions.

You need to use the definition of a tangent bundle.
